# Repetion while importing data from XML ( Simple XML Parser ) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am trying to extract data from an XML as below

```html
<list last_update="2018-12-11 17:37:18" listing_count="196">
    <property last_update="2018-12-10 15:02:21">
    <agent>
    <name>
    <![CDATA[ G. G. ]]>
    </name>
    <email>sales29@shadesproperties.ae</email>
    <phone>+971 50 355 4416</phone>
    <license_no>38729</license_no>
    </agent>
    <parking>1</parking>
    <photo>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/OWWFGpAN3l4tF5eU.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/ZNBpQDrbx7fSURP6.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/DKDkGl1DXb5Ec75E.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/aMUA4rFzFRnr0jru.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/70UFXHqM7OAo3f5h.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/sELG0dzNyOxmwlFE.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/x2S9Q0BvwT1fZUyb.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/s9MDwWwYKeloiibS.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-10-07 16:31:14" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/SahPWXAGL0dAMpMg.jpeg
    </url>
    <url last_update="2018-12-10 14:59:07" watermark="Yes">
    https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1300/iAuYR3KfjNRIAJkk.jpeg
    </url>
    </photo>
    <geopoints>55.34016973,25.2242947</geopoints>
    </property>
</list>
```

I tried loading the data into an importer (provided by Perch CMS) For importing as collection items .

The issue is each collection items have the same set of images .

have a look at the PHP code i use to extract the data .

```html
<?php
include('perch/runtime.php');
$images = array();
$location = array();

$API      = new PerchAPI(1.0, 'my_importer');
$Importer = $API->get('CollectionImporter');
$Importer->set_collection('property');
$Template = $API->get('Template');
$Template->set('content/text', 'content');
$Importer->set_template($Template);
$Importer->empty_collection();
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://shades.mycrm.com/feed/privatesite/0744a0be5fac33c3b3e69c6b26e97d1e") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->children() as $propertylisting) {    
foreach($propertylisting->photo->children() as $image_url) {
$images[] = $image_url->__toString(); 
}
    $location[] = $propertylisting->community->__toString(); 
    try {
    $Importer->add_item([
        'reference_number'   =>  $propertylisting->reference_number  ,
        'description_en'          =>  $propertylisting->description_en  ,
        'title_property'            =>  $propertylisting->title_en  ,
        'property_image_1'    =>  $images[0],
         'property_image_2'   =>  $images[1],
        'property_image_3'    =>  $images[2],
        'property_image_4'    =>  $images[3],
        'property_image_5'    =>  $images[4],
        'property_image_6'    =>  $images[5],
        
    ]);    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error: '.$e->getMessage());
}
} 
$result = array_unique($location);
?>
```

How do i add images into the importer uniquely .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see happening is that you never clear out the `$images` array each time round the loops, so this will mean that instead of building up a list of images for this listing, they will accumulate for all listings.  So simple reset the array for each property listing...

```
foreach($xml->children() as $propertylisting) {    
    // Reset array
    $images = array();
    foreach($propertylisting->photo->children() as $image_url) {
        $images[] = $image_url->__toString(); 
    }
```